# SET a variable inside a CTE

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2012

This is my first time I work with SQLServer 2012, and I have this code that it doesn't work:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ReadCodeBuffer
    @gint bigint,   
    @pres tinyint,
    @level bigint,
    @quantity smallint,
    @xmlGenerated xml OUTPUT
AS

    DECLARE @current_incremental bigint
    DECLARE @counter bigint
    DECLARE @xml XML

    -- Get current incremental.
    set @current_incremental = 
        (SELECT INCREMENTAL
            FROM INCREMENTAL_TABLE
            WHERE GTIN = @gint AND
              PRESENTATION = @pres AND
              LEVEL = @level)

    -- 
    with Numbers as
    (
      select row_number() over(order by 1/0) as N
      from sys.all_objects as o1 cross join
           sys.all_objects as o2
    )
    SET @xml = (
    select @gint as GINT,
           @pres as PRESENTATION,
           @level as LEVEL,
           N + @current_incremental as INCREMENTAL
    from Numbers
    where N < @quantity
    for xml path('row'), root('root'), type)

    SET @xmlGenerated = @xml
GO
```

There is a problem with this piece of code:

```
SET @xml = (
    select @gint as GINT,
           @pres as PRESENTATION,
           @level as LEVEL,
           N + @current_incremental as INCREMENTAL
    from Numbers
    where N < @quantity
    for xml path('row'), root('root'), type)
```

I have these three errors:

```
Incorrect syntax near SET.
Column name N not valid.
Object name 'Numbers' not valid.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to replace `SET` with `SELECT` and it will work

so this

```
SET @xml = (
```

need to be replaced with

```
SELECT @xml = (
```